# size of double array in JNI NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, signal-processing

I am working on some DSP methods on Android using NDK.
I am calling a convolution native method in the main activity like

```
    public native int convolution(double[]xreal,double[]ximag,double[]yreal,double[]yimag,double[]outreal,double[]outimag, int n);
```

In the `convolution.c` file:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_convolution_MainActivity_convolution (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jdoubleArray xreal, jdoubleArray ximag, jdoubleArray yreal, jdoubleArray yimag, jdoubleArray outreal, jdoubleArray outimag, jsize n)
jdouble *xr,*xi, *yr, *yi;
jsize size = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, xreal);//-----------changes
xr = (*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env, xreal, 0);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,"MyTag", "The value of xr is %d", sizeof(xr)/sizeof(xr[0]);
xi = (*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env, ximag, 0);
yr = (*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env, yreal, 0);
yi = (*env)->GetDoubleArrayElements(env, yimag, 0);
```

The problem is I get the correct sizes of `xreal,ximag,yreal,yimag` which is 5442, but the size of xr is always 1.
Can anyone point out the problem please?

Comment: Do you get the correct n? If not, it might be an extra argument.

Comment: n is correct (=5442), the same as size

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `sizeof` to get the size of an array passed to you as a pointer - `sizeof(xr)` only gives you the size of the pointer variable. You should use `GetArrayLength` (and the `size` variable) instead, as you do correctly in the line above.

Comment: Yeah, indeed, it's `sizeof(xr)/sizeof(xr[0])`

Comment: i tried what you said @mstorsjo it gave me this: 'Invalid indirect reference 0x428bc528 in decodeIndirectRef '